# Download multiple dynamic webpages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to download multiple web pages that looks like this:
https://domain.index.aspx?place=&time=123

How can I download each page that ends with a three digit number?
I tried `https://domain.index.aspx?place=&time=+[0-9]`
and `'\d{3}` but both do not work.

thanks

Comment: What has this to do with beautifulsoup??? BeautifulSoup is a parser and not an URL download tool. urllib2 is your friend - or ?

Comment: Are you asking how to scrape all links from a page that end in a 3 digit number?

Comment: yes all the pages end with three digits numbers, i'm using urllib2 to download.

Comment: ``[0-9]`` and ``\d{3}`` are symbolic notations that are usable only in a regex's pattern  -.- By the way, I think it's a coarse welcome to a new user to downvote her first question. There are users with high rep who are upvoted even when their answers are wrong, and a newbie should be downvoted just for a clumsy question ?!! So I upvote to make up for this unfairness

Answer (score 1):

You must know the ending numbers of the different pages you want to download and do, for exemple:

```
for numb in ('458', '123', '453'):
    sock = urllib.urlopen('https://domain.index.aspx?place=&time=' + numb)
```

or if you want to try all the numbers with 3 digits:

```
for numb in xrange(0,1000):
   sock = urllib.urlopen('https://domain.index.aspx?place=&time=' + str(numb).zfill(3))
```